# That vs Which and comma usage in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, commas, that-vs-which

> A1. The dogs, *which* barked in the night-time, did not recognize the thief.
>
> A2. The dogs *which* barked in the night-time did not recognize the thief.
>
> B1. The dogs, *that* barked in the night-time, did not recognize the thief.
>
> B2. The dogs *that* barked in the night-time did not recognize the thief.

As far as I know, both A1 and A2 are "standard" English and the their meaning, as one can notice, is rather different.

Could one replace *which* with *that* in both A1 and A2 cases without infringing the rules of grammar? Could the absence or the presence of punctuation (please, note the parenthetical commas) interfere with or impede in any way this replacement?

Comment: As the answers at Mistu4u's link tell you, B1 is not permitted: *which* must be employed in non-restrictive clauses, which are signalled by commas. The others are just fine.

Comment: @StoneyB: If that rule were to be applied with any consistency, I doubt I'd be finding [1,730,000 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22those+which+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books for *"those **which** do"*. I personally have cheerfully ignored the rule all my life, and I certainly don't consider myself illiterate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You misunderstand me; I was unintentionally ambiguous. "In non-restrictive clauses, *which* must be employed." There's no rule (despite the pundits) against using *which* in a restrictive clause; but there is a rule against using *that* in a non-restrictive clause.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, I certainly can't criticise the restatement! I think it says everything OP might need to know, so I'll upvote your comment rather than any answers!

Answer (score 4):

> **A1.** The dogs, which barked in the night-time, did not recognize the thief.

All the dogs barked; none of them recognized the thief.

> **A2.** The dogs which barked in the night-time did not recognize the thief.

Those dogs which barked did not recognize the thief. (There's an implication that there were other dogs, which did not bark.)

> **B1.** The dogs, that barked in the night-time, did not recognize the thief.

I don't think this sentence is possible.

> **B2.** The dogs that barked in the night-time did not recognize the thief.

This one's fine. It means the same as **A2**, and [some people prefer it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32/191), to avoid overworking *which*.

Comment: -1  In this context this is just too complex an analysis. You're giving too much information and getting away from the point of the question. Moreover, in this specific context, neither A1 nor B1 are natural sounding sentences, though they are grammatically correct.

Comment: @Aerovistae. I'm interested in your contention that sentence B1 is grammatically correct. I don't think it is.

Comment: Yeah you win out on that one, I don't know why I said that.

Answer (score -4):

Really, you could use either *that* or *which* in this context. *Which* belongs to a slightly higher language. Either is correct, though.

The comma is simply wrong. It is not needed. I'll leave it to someone else who feels like explaining when to use a comma and when not to. I can't bring myself to get into it right now.

Comment: -1. A1 and A2 are both accurate, and mean different things.

Comment: He's not asking about that kind of sentence. For his intended meaning, it's wrong.

Comment: Quote from the question: "As far as I know, both A1 and A2 are "standard" English and the their meaning, as one can notice, is rather different."

Comment: In fact, OP specifically notes that two different meanings are in play here.

Comment: -1 No references to support your claims, and your laziness (we all get lazy, so I don't blame you for that) is no excuse for not explaining your "answer": If you feel too lazy to explain yourself, then don't answer. Wait until you've got the energy before making _pronunciamentos_. Support what you say and they become claims and, possibly, good answers rather than mere expressions of personal opinion.