# Thank you for the most superb dinner (that) I’ve ever eaten

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis

Sentence 1:Thank you for the most superb dinner **that** I’ve ever eaten.

Sentence 2:Thank you for the most superb dinner I’ve ever eaten

Which sentence is more natural to you?

Comment: The answers to that question might answer your question [Why is “that”/“which” omitted in this sentence?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4549/2818)

Comment: *Thank you for the most delicious dinner I ever had.* For food, delicious fits better than 'superb' I think. Also, when you talk about meals, you better 'have' them and not 'eat'.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a matter of opinion,  I believe that sentence 2, with the "that" omitted, is more natural to say than sentence 1.

The reason I believe is that if you look at literature, shorter sentences are used to "hype" up the reader, and for them to read faster.  It's the same with sentences that you say, you want to convey to the listener how nice their meal was, and you want that to be as short and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In English, use: that/which/who when you're talking about the *subject*.

You can - but you don't have to - use: that/which/who when you're talking about the **object**.

I'm the person. *I* liked the **cake**.

I'm the person who/that liked the cake.

That's the cake. I liked it.

That's the cake I liked.

Therefore:

Thank you for the most superb dinner I’ve ever eaten!