# What relative pronoun should I use here? which or that?

Tags: relative-pronouns, restrictive-clauses

Can I change "which" to "that" as it is a Restrictive Clause?

> Catholics were aligned with Southerners in the Democratic Party at midcentury, a coalition ***which*** was exceedingly unfavorable to Catholics on the issue of public aid.

**EDIT** I have read the question [Is there any difference between “which” and “that”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5/is-there-any-difference-between-which-and-that), but "a coalition" is a modifier or additional information of "Democratic Party" so I think it is better to use "that" instead of "which" to make the sentence restrictive clause. Can I use "that" instead of "which"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between “which” and “that”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5/is-there-any-difference-between-which-and-that)

Comment: I know the difference between "which" and "that" but here "a coalition" is a modifier or additional information of "Democratic Party" so I think it is better to use "that" instead of "which" to make the sentence restrictive clause.

Comment: You may want to look over some of the answers for this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1243/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A restrictive relative clause  may use either *that* or the appproriate *wh-* form as relativizer—or, in some circumstances, **no** relativizer. None is "better" or "worse" than the others: it's a free stylistic choice.

Consequently, you may write any of the following:

> Catholics were aligned with Southerners in the Democratic Party at midcentury, a coalition ***which*** was exceedingly unfavorable to Catholics on the issue of public aid.
>
> Catholics were aligned with Southerners in the Democratic Party at midcentury, a coalition ***that*** was exceedingly unfavorable to Catholics on the issue of public aid.
>
> Catholics were aligned with Southerners in the Democratic Party at midcentury, a coalition ***∅*** exceedingly unfavorable to Catholics on the issue of public aid.

Note, by the way, that what matters here is the relationship between the relative clause and the term, *coalition*, which it modifies; the syntactic role of *coalition* within the sentence is entirely irrelevant. In fact *coalition* is **not** a modifier, restrictive or non-restrictive, on *Democratic party*: it's an appositive which restates the entire main clause.