# Which word should be used, "what" or "which"?

Tags: difference

> A camera is something […] is used for taking pictures.

What word should be inserted, *which* or *what*?

Comment: Really, your choice is between _that_ and _which_. If you Google "that vs which", you'll be able to find several explanations (that/which) can help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5/is-there-any-difference-between-which-and-that

Comment: That's the problem! There are 4 possible variants in the test: what, which, whose, whom. There's no "that". So I am to choose between what and which. And I can't make my choice ((

Comment: Alternatively, omit the "is" and you have "A camera is something used for taking pictures". And after only just seeing that comment about the test, in this case you would choose "which".

Comment: Furthermore, where I live, people with no discipline in their command of English may use "what", this is poor grammar, in fact plain wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *which* is a standard choice.  *What* is not, although using *what* in this manner has a long history in some nonstandard dialects.

As the comments say, *that* would also work; see the [question linked by bytebuster](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5/is-there-any-difference-between-which-and-that) for details, and [StoneyB's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32/230) in particular.

Answer (score -1):

Both answers are actually wrong in this case.

> A camera is something what is used for taking pictures.

Is just completely wrong, no question.

> A camera is something which is used for taking pictures.

Needs extra punctuation to be grammatically correct:

> A camera is something, which is used for taking pictures.

This reveals the true emphasis of this sentence, and shows that it's wrong. 'Which' is used to show a characteristic that applies to all the things, in this case all the "somethings," which is obviously incorrect. (There are somethings that aren't used for taking pictures!)

The correct way to say it would be

> A camera is something that is used for taking pictures.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand the distinction between relative *which* and *that*, and why relative *which* is sometimes preceded by a comma. Relative *which* may head **both** restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses; non-restrictive clauses are set off with commas. Relative *that* may head **only** restrictive clauses; restrictive clauses are not set off with commas.