# When to use 'which' or 'in which' or 'that' (as relative pronouns)?

Tags: relative-pronouns, pied-piping, that-vs-which

I am confused about when to use:  'which' vs 'in which' vs or 'that'?

Would you please explain it as a writing rule? Here I have an example:

> Authors reported shortened growth period and slower radial growth rate for low soil water potential which is directly attributed to the decrease in water potential, rather than to the constraints on carbon availability.

Comment: One thing I can say is that "in which" sounds rather formal. Generally, "in which" is equivalent to "where". To provide a real answer would be something a little too demanding for me at the moment. Please wait for others.

Answer (score 15):

The grammatical distinctions between use of *which* and of *that* are treated [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5/32); it was just the third question asked on this site!

*In which* may head a relative clause **in which** the *which* must stand as the object of the preposition *in*.

> He put the book *in* that cupboard.

There are four ways of expressing *he put the book in* as a relative clause modifying *cupboard*.

1. with a ‘null-relativizer’ → That is the cupboard he put the book **in**.
2. with *that* → That is the cupboard **that** he put the book **in**.
3. with *which* → That is the cupboard **which** he put the book **in**.
4. with *which* and ‘pied-piping’ → That is the cupboard ***in which*** he put the book.

‘Pied-piping’ is the technical term for a *Wh-* relative pronoun’s dragging along the preposition **of which** it is the object when it ‘moves’ to the head of a relative clause from the position which its referent would occupy in the corresponding main clause.

```
     PIED-PIPED                                NOT PIED-PIPED 
     . . . he put the book    in it.           . . . he put the book in   it. 
                                ↓                                          ↓ 
     . . . he put the book  [in which]         . . . he put the book in [which]
                                ↓                                          ↓ 
     ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←                 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←
    ↓                                           ↓
[in which] he put the book                   [which] he put the book in
```

Note that only *Wh-* pronouns may pied-pipe their prepositions. Relative *that* may **not** pied-pipe:

> <sup>∗</sup> That is the cupboard **in that** he put the book.

Note, too, that an apparent ’preposition‘ which acts as a particle in a true phrasal verb may **not** be pied-piped:

> <sup>ok</sup>This is the form **which** you need to fill **in**.
>   <sup>∗</sup>This is the form **in which** you need to fill.

18th century writers on grammar deprecated what we today call the ‘stranded’ preposition—a preposition ending a clause, as in ##1, 2 and 3 above—in the most formal prose. Their objection was aesthetic, not grammatical: it was an age when both poetry and prose were still written primarily for the ear, not the eye, and they felt that in speech unstressed syllables and function words weakened what should be the strongest part of a sentence.

In the 19th century this preference was rigidified by schoolteachers into a hard ‘rule’ forbidding stranded prepositions, and that rule was widely enforced down to quite recent times. Some still maintain it today; but you may generally ignore it.

This does not mean, however, that pied-piping is to be avoided; in fact, recent corpus studies have shown that pied-piping is still more common with *Wh-* relatives than stranding even in spoken English. And pied-piping, in contexts where it is permitted, has the great advantage of making the relationship between the preposition and its object clearer. It **should** be employed wherever many words would separate the *Wh-* relative from the preposition:

> <sup>ok</sup> That is the chest **in which** the long-lost private papers of James Boswell were for almost two centuries stored.
>   <sup>awk</sup>That is the chest **which** the long-lost private papers of James Boswell were for almost two centuries stored **in**.
>
> ---

<sup>∗</sup>  marks an utterance which is not grammatically acceptable.
<sup>awk</sup> marks an utterance which is awkward and should be avoided.

Comment: This is perfect! I love the way you explain "pied-pipe". It's clear and enlightening.

Comment: @StoneyB I may be too clumsy, but I guess I'm confused by the structure of your sentence '‘Pied-piping’ is the technical term for a Wh- relative pronoun’s dragging along the preposition **of which** it is the object when *it* ‘moves’ to the head of a relative clause from the position which its referent would occupy in the corresponding main clause'. Is the bold '**of which**' there a real relative pronoun which is leading a relative clause 'it is the object ...', or it is just a noun word 'of which' specifying the 'of which' in the original sentence?

Comment: And what do you mean by the first and second 'it' in "**it** is the object when **it** moves ..". This sentence is quite challenging to me:-( Thanks.

Comment: Adding this topic up which involve more than just `in`

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322836/how-to-correctly-apply-in-which-of-which-at-which-to-which-etc