# from which or that?

Tags: relative-pronouns, pied-piping

Can you tell me which one is correct?

> 1. Emily Dickinson's garden was a place **from which she drew** great inspiration for her poems.
> 2. Emily Dickinson's garden was a place **that she drew** great inspiration for her poems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To imitate [one of the best answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14664/3281) I've read here...

You have four possible ways to rephrase that sentence:

1. with a ‘null-relativizer’ → Emily Dickinson's garden was a place she drew great inspiration for her poems **from**.
2. with *that* → Emily Dickinson's garden was a place **that** she drew great inspiration for her poems **from**.
3. with *which* → Emily Dickinson's garden was a place **which** she drew great inspiration for her poems **from**.
4. with *which* and ‘pied-piping’ → Emily Dickinson's garden was a place **from which** she drew great inspiration for her poems.

So, only your first alternative is correct. The second one will need *from* at the end of sentence. Please also note that the relative *that* may not pied-pipe.

You can find more details on 'pied-piping' in StoneyB's answer mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

The answer can also be determined logically. The garden was the source of her inspiration. Her inspiration was the garden; it was *from* the garden. So, "from which" is correct.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Nice self-edit to remove your question-in-an-answer.