# Can I use "which" instead of "that" in these sentences?

Tags: word-choice

> ​1. The darts contained a drug **that** put the wolves to sleep.

Can I also use "**which**" to take place of "**that**" in this sentence?

Plus, what about using "**which**" to take place of "**that**" in these sentences:

> ​2. Few kids in the survey met the guidelines for physical activity **that** raises the heart rate and makes you breathe harder.
>
> ​3. Pi came to an island **that** is sweet by day but dangerous by night.
>
> ​4. Other major effects have included programs to destroy rabbit holes or use viruses **that** sicken and kill rabbits.
>
> ​5. The answer is probably as simple as the fact **that** people change.

Honestly, I am quite doubtful about the last sentence, for the "**that**" in it seems unchangeable.

Anybody help?

Comment: I like this StoneyB's answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14664/3281. (There is a link of another question in that answer too.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go see it. As for now, I am in need for the yes or no answer one by one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sentences 1-4 you have **integrated relatives** (often called "restrictive"), the sort that isn't surrounded by commas.   You can tell these are relative clauses because they have **gaps**—specifically, their subjects are missing.

The gap in each case is left behind by the relative pronoun *which*.  But in your examples, you've replaced these relative pronouns with *that*.  You can undo this change and put *which* back in its rightful spot, if you like:

> ​1. The darts contained a drug *that/which* [ ____ put the wolves to sleep ] .
>
> ​2. Few kids in the survey met the guidelines for physical activity *that/which* [ ____ raises the heart rate and makes you breathe harder ] .
>
> ​3. Pi came to an island *that/which* [ ____ is sweet by day but dangerous by night ] .
>
> ​4. Other major effects have included programs to destroy rabbit holes or use viruses *that/which* [ ____ sicken and kill rabbits ] .

If these were **supplementary relatives** (often called "non-restrictive"), the sort that's usually surrounded by commas, you wouldn't be able to replace *which* with *that*; you'd be stuck with *which* in each case.

---

In sentence 5 you have something very different!  The clause following *that* is **complete** and therefore contains no **gap**.  And without a gap, there's no place for a relative pronoun like *which*.  The word *that*, therefore, **cannot** be taking the place of *which*; there's no substitution to undo, because *which* wasn't there in the first place.

Instead, this particular *that* is a **subordinator**, introducing a subordinate finite clause:

> ​5. The answer is probably as simple as the fact *that* [ people change ] .

Since this isn't a relative clause, the relative pronoun *which* has no place here.  Since *which* isn't an option, you're stuck with *that* in this example.