# "good about 〜ing" versus "good at 〜ing"

Tags: grammar

> I am good **about** getting things done.
>   I am good **at** getting things done.

So says my grammar book...
But why "about"?
Isn't it "at"?
Is it the same?

Comment: Where did you find the sentence _I am good about getting things done._? Is there any reason why you would think that sentence is correct when it contradicts your book?

Comment: @oerkelens: is there any reason why you think that sentence is incorrect?

Comment: It looked weird to me at first, possibly also due to the original layout of your question. I had not come across _I'm good about something_ in this meaning before, but I have now learned that it is not an uncommon expression :)

Answer (score 3):

"I'm good about" is a colloquial expression, similar to "good at," but expressing a tendency to be disciplined about certain things, and can be trusted to do them:

> I'm good about not eating after 8pm.
>
> I'm usually good about not putting my ex-husband down in front of the
>   children, but sometimes I just lose my cool - especially on the phone.
>
> My sons are pretty good about cleaning up after themselves. I hardly
>   ever have to remind them.

"I'm good at" expresses a talent or affinity for something:

> I'm good at editing and I'm a fast typer.
>
> My wife was very good at bookkeeping - she paid all the bills.

In your sentences, the first one expresses that the speaker knows that things have to get done and is disciplined about doing that, does them in a timely manner. In the second sentence, the speaker is very talented in that respect and knows how to get things done, it a good time manager, etc.

Comment: I'm the source.

Comment: I made the answer up from my 50 years of speaking English as a native, 30 of those years working as a professional editor. If that's not good enough, let me know and I'll remove my answer. You have some attitude!

Comment: @username901345 From some reading in meta, it seems like there is a faction here that's pedantic about references.  It makes me afraid that this is going to be just another one of those "mechanical research turk" stack exchanges.

Comment: sorry. I didn't mean to hurt you. But being an editor for many years doesn't render you Omnipotent. Language is Science. Evidence is Everything.

Comment: @username901345 except for when the (now deleted) answer on [This question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29754/in-the-way-in-which) used a reference to define `in the way` as obstruction or blocking

Comment: You didn't "hurt" me, but your wording could have been more civilized. Furthermore, I don't consider myself in any way "omnipotent," however as a native I have an instinct and feel for the language that speaks for itself. Your question is about easy, everyday colloquial expressions, which any native could answer of the top of their head. If I had to research references, I would simply go to Google and find them. However you could have done that yourself in the first place and avoided asking. So you're welcome!

Comment: @username901345 The fact that people are urged to mention their sources when quoting something is understandable, but if you refuse to accept an unchallenged answer from a native speaker, I suggest you should not accept the opinion of someone just because it is published in a book. Good luck finding any but the most basic matters on which you can cite peer-reviewed research that all linguists agree on. Language can be approached scientifically, but that does not make it physics or mathematics. On the contrary!

Comment: Alright, Now I see your point of view. I submit to you. Sorry, guys.

Comment: Off-topic! Your icon makes me think of you as a college student. If I may ask, who is that? @CocoPop

Comment: It's me - at 48 :)

Comment: @SamIam - Perhaps [my](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1117) meta post was misconstrued? I didn't mean to say that an answer without a published literary reference is substandard, or that personal experience can't be relied upon. My beef was with answers that are unsupported, **with no elaboration**. For example, this question asks, "Is it the same?" I would have had a problem with an answer that said, "No, they are not the same" – and ended at that. However, this answer explains the difference, accompanied by several excellent examples. I have no problem with this fine answer.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things.

if you're good "*good **at** getting things done*", you're saying that you're  **skilled** at getting things done. It doesn't imply that you will actually choose to get those things done.

if you're "*good **about** getting things done*" it means that people can rely on you to get things done.  It doesn't imply any degree of skill directly, It just means that you will get the tings done.