# "in the way which" vs. "in the way in which"

Tags: difference

Can I always interchange "in the way [which](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14591)" + ["in the way in which"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29754), like in the quotations beneath? If not, when to use which? What happens if I swap them in the quotations beneath?

### Instantiations of  ["in the way in which"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29754)

> [They wish, I think on neurological grounds, to distinguish
> three senses: a pressure-sense, a warm-and-cold sense, and a pain-sense. Would
> we be happy to accept their pain-sense as a sense **in the way in which** sight or
> smell is a sense? I think not; for to do so would involve regarding the fact that we
> do not "externalize" pains as a mere linguistic accident.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Studies_in_the_Way_of_Words/8r78DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22in+the+way+in+which%22&pg=PT225&printsec=frontcover)

Paul Grice. *Studies in the Way of Words* (1991). I don't see page number.

> [Colors are attributes, and do not have matter **in the way in which** sensible bodies do. However, there is a way in which they do have matter, namely by analogy.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theory_and_Practice_in_Aristotle_s_Natur/oYhsCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22in+the+way+in+which%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover)

Edited by David Ebrey. *Theory and Practice in Aristotle's Natural Science* (2015). Page 19.

> [The power of language is overwhelming and this is shown **in the way in which** words are used to define, portray and explain people and situations. With this in mind, then, it is interesting to note how the language of "special needs" has always been composed of words and images which foster fear, mistrust, loathing and hostility - "idiot", "imbecile" and "moron" are frequently used as terms of abuse.](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.4324/9781315043166/bad-mouthing-jenny-corbett)

### Instantiations of "in the way which"

> ##### King James Bible
>
> I will instruct thee and teach thee **in the way which** thou shalt go: I will guide thee with mine eye.
>
> ##### New American Standard Bible
>
> I will instruct you and teach you **in the way which** you should go; I will advise you with My eye upon you.

I got no space to quote all other versions of [Psalm 32:8e](https://biblehub.com/psalms/32-8.htm) that use  "**in the way which**".

> [Directly after Hamlet's death Fortinbras enters in triumph from his expedition to Poland, and English ambassadors arrive with news of the death of Rosencrantz and Guildenstern, wrought through the dispatch forged by Hamlet and delivered to the English King by their own hands. A rapid use has been made of the ten practicable days, **in the way which** we have already seen practiced by Shakespeare. But his scheme of time in Hamlet is absolutely flawless and self-consistent, from the interior point of view.](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1885/04/time-in-shakespeares-plays/633267/)

Henry A. Clapp. *Time in Shakespeare's Plays*. April 1885 Issue, *The Atlantic*.

> [Hear me, I am older than thou ; thou art like to meet with, meet with, **in the way which** thou goest, wearisomeness, painfulness, hunger, perils, nakedness, swords, lions, dragons, darkness, and, in a word, death, and what not: these things are certainly true, having been confirmed by many testimonies. And should a man so carelessly cast away himself, by giving heed to a stranger?](https://everything2.com/title/The+Pilgrim%2527s+Progress%253A+Part+I%253A+Worldly+Wiseman)

John Bunyan. *The Pilgrim's Progress*.

Comment: In the first set, _way_ means _manner_ - 'doing things in a certain way'. In the second set it means _route_ (note that the KJV and Bunyan are seventeenth century English) or, in the Shakespeare criticism, _method_ - 'he practised a certain way of representing time'.

Comment: I think in all of your examples (probably all possible occurrences of the sequence ***in the way in which***) you can discard either JUST the second ***in*** OR the two words ***in which***. Come to that, you can probably always discard the first ***in*** as well.  And I don't think this is affected by whether "way" is a literal "route, path" or a figurative "manner, method".

Comment: We had that very psalm in church this morning in a modern version which reads "I will instruct you and teach you in the way that you should go."