# of which each VS. each of which

Tags: clauses

> If Country exists, if Country is a natural necessity like bread, **of which each of us** must eat in order not to die of hunger, somebody must go to defend it.

Would you please show me if the bold parts mean the same thing?

**each of us of which**

What is more, could you teach me other possible ways to write the following part?

of which each of which

Thanks in advance

***Updated:***

In order to avoid ambiguity as to why I have raised the question, the following might be useful:

The bungalow, of which the roofs was damaged, had to be corrected.

The bungalow, the roofs of which was damaged, had to be corrected.

[enter link description here](http://web.mit.edu/alam/Public/weblog/War.htm)

Comment: A minor note: _roof_ is usually singular.  One bungalow has one _roof_, not _roofs_.

Comment: I have a feeling that I have seen this kind of question here. And there the OP had shared some link about this kind of usage. Just can't find it :-(

Comment: Both **The bungalow, of which the roofs was damaged, had to be corrected** and **The bungalow, the roofs of which was damaged, had to be corrected** are correct but these sentence are not similar to the sentence where **of which each of us** occurs. The difference is that **the roof** is attached with the antecedent, but **each of us** is not attached wit the antecedent.

Comment: Oh my mistake in my previous comment. As @stangdon said, I should have used **roof** instead of **roofs**. I just copy pasted those sentences without much attention on that word :-(

Answer (score 2):

This example is somewhat archaic; I would not expect to find it in modern English prose.  The key to understanding is that it was and is common to say that one "eats bread" but it used to be also common to say that one "eats OF bread", meaning the same thing.

we must eat OF bread
so, bread is something OF WHICH we must eat

How many of us eat? Each of us!

Thus: ". . .bread, of which each of us must eat. . ."

Answer (score 1):

> Each of us of which

This isn't sensible to use or to hear, at least in this context.

> ...of which each of us...

"Which" is a pronoun that has begun a relative clause. There is also this rule of grammar, which I believe you know, that a preposition is best to come before the relative pronoun if necessary for the main element of the clause. "Each of us" is the subject of a this sentence:

> Each of us must eat in order not to die of hunger.

So I really don't get why one would think about writing the latter phrase you emboldened.

Answer (score 1):

I have listed down some ways to use **of which** form:

> The house **whose** roof was damaged is said to be haunted.

Here the antecedent of **whose** is **house** - an inanimate object. We can replace **whose** in these cases with **of which**.

> The house **of which the roof** was damaged is said to be haunted.

The other way of saying it -

> The house **the roof of which** was damaged is said to be haunted.

Other examples -

> There are few questions **the answer of which** I don't know.
>
> There are few questions **of which** I don't know the answer.
>
> There are few questions **which** I don't know the answer *of*.

But the following sentence is ungrammatical and hence not accepted.

> - He came up with a strange plan **which** the purpose of escapes me. (INCORRECT)

Partitive examples -

> She hadn't kept copies of her letters, **only five of which** he had answered.
>
> She hadn't kept copies of her letters, **of which** he had answered *only five*.

But the following is wrong -

> - She hadn't kept copies of her letters, **which** he hadn't answered *only five of* (INCORRECT)

The following links are useful

1. [Link 1](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses)
2. [Link 2](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv286.shtml)
3. [Link 3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/when-to-use-which-or-in-which-or-that-as-relative-pronouns)

Comment: A.There are few questions which I don't know the answer of.B.She hadn't kept copies of her letters, which he hadn't answered only five of  I am wondering why A is correct but B is incorrect!!

Comment: @nima A good question. Even I don't know the reason. But it's this way. A learner should at least know that when a quantity is involved such as in sentence #B that construction is not allowed. We can't move the preposition at the end that way.