# Which vs of which?

Tags: relative-clauses

Here is a sentence from the Examination:

> The science medicine, *which* progress has been rapid lately, is perhaps the most important of all sciences.

As I know, `which` clause can still + Object, so it's very nearly with `of which`. In that sentence (find an error), the answer: `Which` is wrong but no has answer (I think is `of which`?). But I'm disturbed so much. Please help me to classify them, thanks.

Comment: I think you probably want *in which*. "Progress has been very rapid **in** medicine lately."

Comment: Hm, I have found the right answer: `in which` = `when`. It's so amazing because I often use `which` only, rarely use `of which`, never use `in which`. I hope someone will explain me more about them, thanks so much!

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, you're right. May you explain me more sir?

Comment: *in which* doesn't mean *when*. *Which* replaces *science medecide*. Perhaps you meant where or something?

Comment: This is an instance of "pied piping"; click [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pied-piping) for questions about this.

Comment: @StoneyB. Thanks for help. I will check it out. If I need your assistance more, I will tag you later (please forgive me).

Comment: I suddenly realized that this may also intend to represent the possessive relative *whose*: "Medicine's progress has been very rapid recently". *Whose* acts as the possessive for both *who* and *which*.

Comment: If this was from an "examination", I suggest whoever set the test wasn't a native speaker. The subject of the sentence would almost always be *The science **of** medicine* (and to continue, my choice would be *... **within** which progress has been rapid **of late***).

Comment: @StoneyB **of which** is the correct one - *"The science medicine, of which progress has been rapid lately, is perhaps the most important of all sciences."*

Comment: This answer might help - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49493/3463

Comment: @Man_From_India That may be what is meant, but it's unlikely any contemporary Anglo writer would use it: we'd say "...whose progress..." or "...the progress of which..."

Comment: @StoneyB Ah I see. So it sounds a little oldish. Personally I haven't seen or heard such usage outside grammar books :-) btw I also think *in which* is also correct.

Comment: Hmm... I would use *where*, but see the Usage note here: [where](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/where). Personally I don't have a problem with *in which*.

Comment: I wouldn't use `which` at all. I'd rewrite the entire thing into separate sentences as it contains two separate ideas, one of `which` is regarding progress, and another `which` is an opinion about the importance thereof. `Lately, the science of medicine has progressed rapidly. It is perhaps one of the most important sciences.`

Comment: I think native speakers would tend to say "medical science" rather than "the science of medicine" unless trying to sound a little extra pompous on purpose — and "the science medicine" even more so, since that's not a typical construct. See [Google Ngram of these three phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+science+medicine%2Cthe+science+of+medicine%2Cmedical+science&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20science%20of%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedical%20science%3B%2Cc0) (and note "the science medicine" doesn't occur at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The science of *'medicine'* is the subject there and the use of commas at the beginning and end of the sentence talks about the type of the sentence which is known as a non-relative clause. This means the string between those two commas is merely for additional information removing which the sentence can stand all alone.

> New York city, ***which*** is a very good place to visit, saw a great fall in tourism last year.

[mark two commas]

> The science medicine, **which** progress has been rapid lately, is perhaps the most important of all sciences.

Here, the pronoun *'which'* lacks in introducing the noun properly. *'Whose progress'*? *'Progress in which field...?'*

Adding a preposition or changing the pronoun work.

> The science medicine, *of which* (the) progress has been rapid lately, is perhaps the most important of all sciences.

OR

> The science medicine, *whose* progress has been rapid lately, is perhaps the most important of all sciences.

['whose' can be used for [inanimate objects](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whose?q=whose) as well].

Comment: I would suggest "in" as the preposition, rather than "of" — "progress in some field" is a common expression, and then you don't need the (the).