# Repeated "to" in "to whom something is done to"?

Tags: prepositions, questions, formality, pied-piping

Is there a rule for this? For example, is it correct to say

> To whom will the package be delivered?

or does it have to be

> To whom will the package be delivered **to**?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I didn't know how to properly search for this construction.

Comment: The second one has a superfluous "to" at the end.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Ah, thanks. How bad does it sound?

Comment: Not too bad.  Redundancies like that one sometimes go unnoticed.

Comment: While I agree, and while even native speakers make this error, I do think it makes you sound uneducated.

Comment: The alternatives you are most likely to hear, though, are "to whom will the package be delivered?" or "who will the package be delivered to, or even "whom will the package be delivered to" -- I'd bet (but cannot prove) that the version with double "to"s would be pretty uncommon.

Comment: @Jasper See this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14591/32

Comment: @Jasper It looks pretty good. I might add some stuff about *why* it's called 'pied-piping', unless you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Only one "to" in needed.

> To whom will the package be delivered?

Adding another "to" at the end is grammatically incorrect. Also, sentences should generally not end in a preposition, though a native speaker is likely to say:

> Who will the package be delivered to?

In an informal setting, the second sentence is preferable if spoken; the first might make you sound pretentious, at least in America. Some teach that ending a sentence with a preposition is always grammatically incorrect, which is a vestige of Latin influence and is [debatable](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/Ending-a-Sentence-with-a-Preposition.html).

Comment: I'd prefer the latter in a formal setting too.