# With whom used on things instead of persons

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

My native language is German. I always want to say something like:

> *I have this function **with whom** I can do this or that*

is this actually possible to say?

I always thought that ***with whom*** can just be used with persons.

Comment: You thought right. it should be "which" instead of "whom"

Comment: So the final sentence would be: *I have this function **with which** I can do this or that*? If that is the case, can I also say *I have this function **with that** I can do this or that*. The example with ***with that*** sounds kinda weird :D

Comment: Or even simpler: I have this function *to do* this/that!

Comment: @MaulikV Wow, never thought of that because I try to combine my German speaking patterns with my English :D That one is really simple and nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words **who** and **whom** are both pronouns.

We use **who** when referring to a subject in a clause. And we use **Whom** when referring to the object of a clause.
Example:

> Martha(subject) Killed Manny(object).

if we use Who and Whom in the sentence above(this might sound weird), it becomes:

> Who(subject pronoun) killed whom(object pronoun)?

**Who** and **whom** are ***personal*** pronoun which means that they are always used with living beings.

So, it is **not** possible to say:

> I have this function with whom I can do this or that

Alternatively, you can say:

> I have this function to do this/that! **[As MaulikV said.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71907/with-whom-used-on-things-instead-of-persons#comment137649_71907)**

or

> I have this function for this/that [purpose/need].

As for more information, read [this somewhat similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/when-to-use-which-or-in-which-or-that-as-relative-pronouns) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)

---

[Araucaria](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71907/with-whom-used-on-things-instead-of-persons/71909#comment137731_71909):

> We can use who for Subjects, Objects and Objects of prepositions. We don't need to use whom for these. We can use whom whenever the relative pronoun isn't the Subject of the main verb in the relative clause.

Comment: We can use *who* for Subjects, Objects and Objects of prepositions. We don't need to use *whom* for these. We can use *whom* whenever the relative pronoun isn't the Subject of the main verb in the relative clause. (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: @Araucaria no problem :)

Comment: @Araucaria I gave a quick basic outline of "Who" vs "Whom" :)

Comment: Yes, agreed. However, your answer does make it sound as if *who* isn't used for objects and so forth :)

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, agreed. However, your comment does explain that who can be used for objects, objects of prepositions. :) Thanks :D

Comment: Yes, agreed. *But*, it would be better if you put that info in your answer. Not everyone reads the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Whom is used to refer to a person, you can use which or you can simply say

> I have this function by which I can do this or that.