# The use of "with" in the sentence "The tone with which he spoke drained Rhonin of all animosity"

Tags: prepositions, pied-piping

> The tone **with** which he spoke drained Rhonin of all animosity - Warcraft: War of the Ancients #1

Why did "with" placed in the position like this? As my personal's knowledge the word "with" can be deleted, without any change in the meaning of the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: You may find "pied-piping" in [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14664/3281) helpful.

Comment: You don't speak a tone, you speak *with* a (certain) tone. You can refer to the tone: *I don't like the tone of your answer or tone of your voice*, but you would say *I don't like the tone with which you spoke to me*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

> "The tone with which he spoke drained Rhonin of all animosity." [correct]

The prepositional phrase "with which he spoke" modifies "The tone," and becomes part of the complete subject ("The tone with which he spoke"). A native speaker would never say "The tone which he spoke," because "the tone" refers to ***how*** something was said in this instance, how it was spoken. However, if you wanted to eliminate the prepositional phrase, you could correctly write,

> "His tone drained Rhonin of all animosity." [also correct]

Does this difference make sense to you? Here are two more examples in response to your comment.

> "The force with which he hit him killed his opponent." [correct]

and,

> "The finesse with which he wielded his sword was unequaled among men." [correct]

Comment: So how can I use "with" in others circumstance? Which the same as this.

Comment: I added two more examples to my answer. Do these help?