# Which is correct - 'the place that I met you at' or 'the place that I met you'?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, syntax

I have a sentence: This is the place where I met you.
Then: This is the place that I met you.
And: This is the place that I met you **at**.

Do I need to write this preposition (at) at the end of this sentence?

Comment: *This is the place where we (had) met*

Comment: Related, [When to use 'which' or 'in which' or 'that' (as relative pronouns)?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/when-to-use-which-or-in-which-or-that-as-relative-pronouns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and the second sentence are grammatically correct.
The third sentence is also grammatically correcr but it is informal.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>grammatical</sup>This is the place where I met you.

<sup>ungrammatical</sup>This is the place **the** I met you.

<sup>colloquial</sup>This is the place that I met you at.

Comment: In the context of 'place', I think *where* is better!

Comment: I would not disagree.

Comment: @TRomano The question was meant to be whether the second and the third sentence is correct and which is better. The first is just for context - that one is probably the best.

Comment: @Vilican, neither of your alternatives with their *that*-clauses is an improvement on the first sentence. We can say simply *This is where I met you.*   Where I come from, people do say things like "Where did you see him at?" but that sort of colloquialism is regarded as non-standard because it is not part of the general dialect.

Comment: @TRomano - I edited the second sentence - that was a typo. Some background - our English teacher tried to search for it and we (the class) too, but we found nothing much. Also, changing the sentence is not the thing I want now (I know it could be better). And I know the first is the best, so I ask which is better - second or third?

Comment: I'm not in this to help people decide between bad choices.