# What does 'for which' here refer to? Does it mean 'because of which'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, clauses

I read a sentence from a text. I somehow can understand the sentence, but I found that I couldn't analyse the structure of it:-(

> Included among such Lipschitz paths are all piecewise smooth paths, for which the generalized definitions of path integrals (with respect to Lipschitz paths) are thus seen  to reduce to the definitions given earlier (with respect to piecewise smooth paths)

In this sentence, the words in parenthesis are added by myself, i.e., the original sentence doesn't contains those words. I added them to provide context for you. 'Lipschitz path' and 'piecewise smooth path' are two concepts in math, on both of which we can define 'path integrals'. I think the real meanings of those math concepts don't matter. You can see it this way that 'Lipschitz paths' is a larger class of 'paths' which contains 'piecewise smooth paths'. I also think I can understand the sentence right. It means,

> Lipschitz paths included all piecewise smooth paths (in other words, piecewise smooth paths are a special class of Lipschitz paths), so the definition of path integrals on Lipschitz paths can be seen to reduce to the definition of path integrals on piecewise smooth paths given earlier.

After transformation, I found that I couldn't find a subject or object that 'for which' refers to in the latter sentence. But 'for which' must refer to something so that we can transform the second part of the latter sentence to a clause in the first sentence, right?

In my opinion, 'for which' is a bit redundant, or it just means 'because of which'?

Comment: piecewise smooth paths, I guess.

Comment: IMNSHO (and I'm on shaky ground here because I know nothing about Lipschitz paths), the sentence is strange and probably doesn't convey the intended meaning. A minimal fix, which could make the sentence work, is *All piecewise smooth paths are included among such Lipschitz paths, for which the generalized definitions of path integrals (with respect to Lipschitz paths) are thus seen to reduce to the definitions given earlier (with respect to piecewise smooth paths)*. (It's still not the best possible way to deliver the message, IMHO, though; but at least it should say what it was meant to say.)

Comment: Suggested reading: [pied-piping](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14591/3281).

Comment: @DamkerngT. Sorry that I don't understand why you bother to use an inverted sentence to replace the first part of my transform. I think the two sentences don't make a difference ...

Comment: No, I didn't replace your transformed sentence. I edited the original sentence. Let's try a simpler example. Compare: *This book was written by Henry, in which his last poem appears.* vs. *Henry wrote this book, in which his last poem appears*. Which one makes more senses?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Frankly, the two sentences are the same to me:-( But it seems the first one sounds more natural to me. I'm really interested in how you would understand them?

Comment: Don't worry. If you can't understand it, it's my fault (because I can't find or make a better example). In my last attempt, I'd like to give you a link to [this page](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleDangling.htm), and another pair of alternatives as a puzzle(!), between *We take increased devotion to that cause from these honored dead for which they gave the last full measure of devotion* and *From these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion*. Hope it might be thought-provoking a bit. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. The page you gave is excellent and I did all the exercises! I think I understand your idea now. For your last pair of examples, the second one is clearer and less misleading, because 'for which' is referring to 'that cause', not 'honored dead'. And as for my question, you think 'for which' is referring to 'Lipschitz paths', not 'piecewise smooth paths'. Right?

Comment: Exactly, on all counts! The way the original sentence puts it can easily make the reader think that the "for which" clause modifies "all piecewise smooth paths", but how can that be when we've got "with respect to Lipschitz paths" in the parentheses? So, the sentence is a bit confusing. BTW, I'm glad you like that page. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sina is correct that "for which" refers to "all piecewise smooth paths", answering your first question. Specifically, "which" refers to the piecewise smooth paths.

For your second question, "for which" does not mean "because of which". The latter part of the sentence is a description (the generalized definitions... are thus seen to...), and "for which" connects that description to the noun that is described (all piecewise smooth paths, as above). I wouldn't say that "for which" is redundant here because without it the rest sentence as written would be difficult to interpret. But the sentence can be re-written, as in your transformation, in ways that do not require the "for which" phrase at all to connect sentence elements together.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I can understand that if omitting the 'for which', this sentence is somehow incomplete, or wrong. But if, as you said, it is difficult to interpret it when omitting it, I think there must be a grammatical reason for this usage. But I can't find a grammatical justification for this attributive clause (It is an attributive clause, right?)

Comment: Or I ask it this way, is it grammatically right to use 'which' to connect a noun in main clause to an attributive clause even if 'which' does not refer or replace anything in the attributive clause?

Comment: @Hua An attributive clause must have a subject and verb of its own. In this case we are using "which" as a pronoun, satisfying the requirement for a subject. The antecedent (all piecewise smooth paths) could be used instead of the pronoun, but that would be odd in a single sentence which already explicitly states the antecedent. So "which" is referring to the antecedent (from the previous clause) and, in the attributive clause, serves as the subject (so it does not need to replace or refer to anything there). "Which" is the correct pronoun to use in this case, signifying "one out of a group".