# Can "in which" be used instead of "which" to express something in a more stronger way?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, relative-pronouns

I have used "which" in a situation where two entities use things, but one entity used a different thing in the second time while the other entity stuck to the same thing it used in the first time.

I find it phrased weakly (I mean by weakly that it didn't express the meaning strongly enough):

> "A" changed its key and got XORed with "B" **which** used the same key as in the first time.

What I mean by that sentence is: A trial has occurred where "A" used a different key in the second time of the trial while "B" stuck to the same key it (refers to "B") used for the first time of the trial.

I thought of using **in which** but a user has stated in their [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14664/80554) to a question on ELL:

> *In which* may head a relative clause **in which** the *which* must stand as the object of the preposition in.
>
> > He put the book in that cupboard.

... which leads me to the conclusion that it can't work for my case.

I have also thought of using **where**:

> "A" changed its key and got XORed with "B" **where it** used the same key as in the first time.

But it *kind of* indicates that "B" is a place rather than an entity.

Another way I tried for expressing it:

> "A" changed its key and got XORed with "B" **which in return** used the same key as in the first time.

But "in return" would mean because of the change "A" has done, "B" did that.

---

So, what is the best *relative pronoun* **or** *phrase* that can fit and express the sentence accurately?

Comment: What doe you mean by "xored"?

Comment: It is the xor logic boolean operation, I have used it as a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/XORed) as in what is called [anthimeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't see how the point isn't illustrated strongly enough in the original sentence. From what I can tell, the subordinate clause is providing me with all the information I need, i.e. B remains the same in the second trial.

> But it kind of indicates that "B" is a place rather than an entity.

The issue is not so much that B seems like a place, rather the fact that the "it" following "where" refers to something else entirely, presumably A based on context.

> "A" changed its key and got XORed with "B" which in return used the same key as in the first time.

You could say "which in turn", but I don't think it fits as the "in turn" emphasizes consecutive, dependent events taking place.

The original sentence reads perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks! **which in turn** is what I was looking for. They are indeed consecutive events, "A" step happens before "B" step. (I should have mentioned that, but I thought it was clear.)