# As regards my sentences, would you tell me why it would be incorrect to use "all what"?

Tags: grammar

Consider:

> I would like to review *all that* I learnt.
>   I would like to review *what* I learnt.

I think these two are fine, but I'd like to know why *all what* would be incorrect.

Could anyone possibly elaborate it so that I could understand it well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your title asks about the difference between *which* and *that*, which is treated [**here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5/32), but your sentences use *all that* and *what*. Which are you looking for help with?

Comment: You can review all that you learnt. But you'd have to review all *of* what you learnt. ("All what you learnt " on its own isn't said).

Answer (score 1):

There is a controversy here caused by grammar-checkers in word processor software:

If you write,

I bent over to pick move a broom which was lying in front of the door,"

Microsoft Office is likely to alert you to an error, suggesting that you substitute "which" with "that."

I'm happier with *which* and I wonder if the suggested *that* is not an Americanism. In any case, either will do in this context.

In your own phrase, however:

"I would like to review all that I learnt." is the only of the two options to be correct. "All *what* I learnt" is not English and, unlike what happens with new and catchy terms whose usage might catch on, we tend to pity the person who says "all *what* I learnt," somehow associating it with an underprivileged childhood, I'm ashamed to say!