# Which relativizers may be used in modifying clauses and phrases?

Tags: relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

If a relative clause modifies **a** noun or **a** pronoun in a main clause, then we could use relative pronouns such as that, which, who, whom, whose, and relative adjectives such as where, why.

During reading, I find that sometimes people use a non-restrictive relative clause introduced by "which" to give more information about phrases in the main clause, or comment on part of the main clause or the main clause. Please refer to the following examples. 
So I am wondering whether we should **only use** non-restrictive clauses introduced by "which" in these situations (i.e. giving more information about phrases in the main clause, commenting on part of the main clause or the main clause).

Example:
1: He likes climbing mountains, which is a good exercise.

("which is a good exercise" gives more information about "climbing mountains")

2: He said that he had never seen her before, which was not true.

("which was not true" is a comment on "he had never seen her before")

3: Tom was late, which surprised me.

("which surprised me" is a comment on "Tom was late")

Please help me. I really need your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [“that” and “which” as relative pronoun](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/that-and-which-as-relative-pronoun)

Comment: I'd prefer not to close as a duplicate of a question without any satisfactory answers.  Besides which, it doesn't appear to address this question specifically.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question - you seem to have a good understanding of the issue & the examples given are all correct. What is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: Agree with mc01. Your sense about RC and NRC is okay. What's the problem?

Comment: I am wondering whether we should only use non-restrictive clauses introduced by "which" to give more information about phrases in the main clause, or comment on part of the main clause or the main clause. Can other relative pronouns such as "who", "whom", "that", "whose", "when", "where" or "why" be used in these situations? In other words, if the antecedent being modified is not a noun or a pronoun, but a phrase, part of the main clause, the main clause, is non-restrictive relative clause introduced by "which" the only choice?  Thank you very much!

Comment: As you've probably already noticed, it is that you will usually have to use a supplementary "which" relative clause when the antecedent is a whole clause or a verb phrase. That is the situation you have with your current examples in your post. For your #1 example: "climbing mountains" is the antecedent for your "which" -- *"Climbing mountains is a good exercise"*. And so on for #2 and #3. Integrated relative clauses almost always need to have a noun (actually it's a "nominal") as its antecedent -- the integrated relative clause modifies its antecedent.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the *wh-* relatives except *how* and *why* may head a non-restrictive bound relative clause. (*How* and *why* are only used to head free relative clauses.) *That* does not head a non-restrictive bound relative clause in writing or prepared speech. You will occasionally hear *that* heading non-restrictive bound relatives in spontaneous speech, where the restrictive/non-restrictive distinction is not clearly drawn.

Which you use depends on the gender (person/non-person) of the referent and, in the case of *who/whom/whose*, on the syntactic role of the pronoun.

> I've just bought the new book by Neal Stephenson, **which** I look forward to reading tonight.  ... *The referent is* the new book by Neal Stephenson, *not a person.*
>
> I've just bought the new book by Neal Stephenson, **who** is an author I enjoy tremendously.  ... *The referent is* Neal Stephenson, *a person, and the subject of* enjoy.
>
> I've just bought the new book by Neal Stephenson, **whose** works I always enjoy. ...  *The referent is* Neal Stephenson, *a person, and the possessor of* works.
>
> I've just bought the new book by Neal Stephenson, whom I admire greatly. ... *The referent is* Neal Stephenson, *a person, and the object of* admire.
>
> You will occasionally hear *that* heading non-restrictive bound relatives in spontaneous speech, **where** the restrictive/non-restrictive distinction is not clearly drawn. ... *The referent is* spontaneous speech, *the 'location' of this phenomenon*.
>
> This ambiguity is apparent at pauses, **when** the speaker experiences difficulty projecting the next burst of speech. ... *The referent is* pauses, *the 'occasion' for this phenomenon.*

Comment: But if I say "The sun is shining today, which has been the case all week" - there seem to be no other possibilities other than "which". That seems to me to be what the OP is asking to have confirmed - though I have to say that the answer seems fairly obvious.