# Use of proper words: relative pronouns

Tags: word-usage

Q1: What is the correct one of the words "which" and "that" to use in the following sentence:

> I know the man, **which/that** we met yesterday.

Q2: Is the word "give" and "that" correctly used in the following :

> I **gave** him a watch, **that** he liked, on his birthday.

If there are mistakes in any other part of the question, please correct me.

Comment: If you have in mind what defining or non-defining relative clauses are, then this won't be difficult. 1) it's a defining one and 2) it's a non-defining one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“that” and “which” as relative pronoun](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/that-and-which-as-relative-pronoun)

Answer (score 1):

Relative clauses can be *restrictive* (or defining) and *non-restrictive* (or non-defining).

- In defining relative clauses, we can use the relative pronouns *which, where, who, whose* and we can replace *who, which* with *that*. This type of clause immediately adds *vital* information about the noun and commas aren't used:

  > *I know the man **who/that** we met yesterday.*
- Non-defining relative clauses add *extra* information about the noun, which is unnecessary for the meaning. We put the extra information between commas and the relative pronouns *who, which* cannot be replaced by *that*:

  > *I gave him a watch, **which** he liked, on his birthday.*